# Deleting Duplicate Values Across Rows

Tags: r, duplicates

I would like to delete rows that have the same value across all columns. For example, I have a home and work ID. If a row has the same ID for the home and work location, I would like to delete that complete row. An example is below:

```
Home    Work
4532    4532
3433    3434
2343    2343
```

So for example, I would like to delete the first and third rows because they have the same values for each column. But I am wondering how to do this for all rows this applies to for a pretty large dataset.

Comment: `df[df$Home != df$Work, ]` should work.

Answer (score 1):

You may subset the data frame on the condition that the home and work numbers be different:

```
df_new <- df[df$Home != df$Work, ]
df_new

  Home Work
2 3433 3434
```